# Scrollview is leaving top space

Tags: ios

My scroll view looks like this:

[image]

Then I tried following line:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

> It fixed but scrolling is not working anymore. How can I fix this problem?

My view tree:

[image]

Comment: If I do it, as i said before i can't scroll anymore.

Comment: can you post your constraints for View i.e. under scrollview

Comment: Of course. Scroll view's constraints: http://prntscr.com/a9c2qh, This is view which is under scrollview: http://prntscr.com/a9c2z9

Comment: It not worked :( Still same

Comment: Do you want check with teamviewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104840/discussion-between-ei-captain-and-tolgay-toklar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a problem with your constraints..

You should give a following constraints:

for **scrollview:**

```
pinned all edges with 0
```

for **view under scrollview:**

```
pinned all edges with 0, height constraint and equal width to superview
```

Done.You can now scroll your view

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the top inset as `0` for the `UIScrollView`

```
<ScrollView>.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, nothing changed